# AngularJS - Textbox class names are appended with -add when populate with handheld devices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-animation

I am using angular 1.5. I see the class names of textbox is getting changed to ng-not-empty-add, .ng-dirty-add, .ng-valid-parse-add and .ng-valid-add when the text box is populated with handheld devices. I don't see -add when populated with keyboard.

So my question is
1.What is this -add
2.Can I use this -add to differentiate between handheld and keyboard device entry
3.Or is their any other approach to differentiate handheld and keyboard input(I don't want to use time-based and prefix-based approaches)

I observed the following on debugger mode during keypress event

**Handheld Device**
currentTarget: input#Number.ng-pristine.ng-empty.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required.ng-valid-pattern.ng-valid-maxlength.ng-touched.ng-not-empty-add.ng-pristine-remove.ng-dirty-add.ng-valid-parse-add.ng-valid-add.ng-invalid-remove.ng-valid-required-add.ng-invalid-required-remove

**Keyboard Device**
currentTarget: input#Number.ng-valid-pattern.ng-valid-maxlength.ng-touched.ng-not-empty.ng-dirty.ng-valid-parse.ng-valid.ng-valid-required

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this. The - add is because of animation function. The handheld device calls animation while inserting the textbox. So I added a listener for $animate and using it to differentiate handheld device and keyboard.